# Laravel 4.2 - Adding time to timestamp

Tags: php, laravel-4

In Laravel 4.2, when a record is created in the database, using eloquent, we can have created_at and updated_at timestamps created.

I would like to add a third column to the table I am working with that is called `expires` and I would like to set the value of that column to `created_at + 72 hours`

Is there a "Laravel" way to do this? To access created_at value? Or should I approach this differently?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Laravel's `created_at` is a an instance of Carbon. Using an accessor, we can populate `$model->expires` like so:

```
public function getExpiresAttribute() {
  $expires = clone $this->created_at;
  $expires->addHours(72);
  return $expires;
}
```

If you want to be able to **query** against the value (rather than just calculating for display), though, you'd need to store it in the database. To have it automatically populate, you can tell Laravel it's a date column and use an observer:

```
public function getDates(){
  return ['created_at', 'updated_at', 'expires'];
}

public static function boot() {
  parent::boot();

  self::creating(function($model) {
    $model->expires = clone $model->created_at;
    $model->expires->addHours(72);
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I wasn't aware I can add time so easily. This helped a great deal :)

Comment: @GRowing Laravel uses https://github.com/briannesbitt/Carbon, which is **awesome**.

Comment: I spent the day reading the documentation. Definitely awesome! And IN TIME (relative to my project) so I don't go forth and do all sorts of unnecessary work that Carbon already does.